# Is it possible to restore an ASUS Backup on an emulator?

Tags: restore, bluestacks, emulators, asus-zenfone-5, genymotion

I had created a backup file using Asus Backup app [Link](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/zenui-asus-computer-inc/backup/) [Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.backuprestore) from my Asus ZenFone (Android 5.1).

I have lost my Asus phone and I'd like to restore the backup into an emulator.

1. Does Genymotion have any ASUS VM?
2. Is there any Emulator that support Asus Backup App?
3. Are there ASUS Zenfone Emulators?
4. Can I, in any way use Android Studio to restore my Backup created using ASUS Backup App?
5. Asus Provide System file from there official site. Can I flash that(Custom Rom) into any Emulator?

Is there any way I can install Asus Backup app in Laptop and restore the Backup I have made?

Is there anything that I can try?

Comment: Playstore link gives error in desktop,but opens correctly when choose open with playstore app in android

Comment: The app description is funny: "ASUS Backup will NOT backup the data stored in the internal storage" - if it does not backup the internal storage what else does it backup? Anyway I would first check the backup file itself if it is a known format. Use an hex editor to view it and test to with various tools like 7zip.

Comment: Means It does not backup pictures snd other suffs Example: If you backup Galley app, It doesnt backup images,videos etc... but it does backup Gallery app and App data like app settings etc..

Comment: extension,, format is .abu1

Comment: I think ASUS just just the wrong term because "internal storage" means normally all the data on your internal flash, this includes all apps, all app private data + the internal sdcard folder with music/pictures/videos. If the description would be correct the only part ASUS backup could backup would be data on the external sd-card.

Comment: The description is wrong.. I have used that app many times is past.. It does backup App Data

Comment: @Robert Can I do something with android studio

Comment: Android Studio is for developing apps, not reading Asus backup files. If you are a programmer you can reverse engineer the Asus backup app e.g. using Jadx or apktool. Additionally you can reverse-engineer the backup files you have, but that also requires a bit of experience.

Comment: @Robert Is there any way around by flashing custom rom on an emulator..see 5th point..

Comment: If such a custom ROM would exists, most likely yes. However custom ROMs for emulators are pretty rare as to find one specific for the old Asus device you are searching - unlikely. IMHO if the backup is really of that value to you you should buy a used Asus zenfone. Or try to to sind a smartphone test farm that has Zenphones (a test farm allows to remotely access a physical device for a limited time).

Comment: @Robert https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218061/flash-custom-rom-on-android-emulator